# Use screencapture with PHP exec

Tags: screen-capture, php

I can't get screencapture to work work when triggered with exec() command.

```
$output = exec("/usr/sbin/screencapture -R 0,0,450,150 hehe.png"." 2>&1");
echo $output; //  in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

I am not sure what the `$output` message is trying to convey.

php.ini `disable_functions` is empty.

I have a feeling that this is a osx problem. Can you point me in the right direction regarding solving this problem?

from **man screencapture**

```
SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS
     To capture screen content while logged in via ssh, you must launch
     screencapture in the same mach bootstrap hierarchy as loginwindow:

     PID=pid of loginwindow
     sudo launchctl bsexec $PID screencapture
```

I'm not using any ssh. PID of which process should be used in this case?

```
exec("sudo launchctl bsexec $PID screencapture -R 0,0,450,150 hehe.png");
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69691/discussion-between-patrix-and-sanjihan).

Answer (score 2):

All credit goes to patrix.

The problem stems from OSX preventing php script from executing `screencapture` command. OSX has no problem if you run your script manually, but if it is triggered as a response to a GET or POST request, than it raises the red flag.

To solve this 3 steps are needed:

1. Add permission to the user that is running httpd (and php) to execute `sudo` `launchctl` without password. In my case it is `daemon`. I got it from Activity Monitor. Edit `/etc/sudoers` with

   ```
   daemon ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/launchctl
   ```
2. get the PID of `loginWindow`. you can use ActivityMonitor for that. PID is subjected to changes so to bullet proof yourself use:

   ```
   pgrep loginwindow
   ```
3. update your `screencapture` command:

   ```
   sudo launchctl bsexec PIDNUMBERHERE screencapture [options] path/image.png
   ```

---

It might be worth mentioning that step 1 adds a slight security risk and probably shouldn't be used in an internet-facing environment (especially with a PHP solution where everybody can easily read the source code).